# Call a rest API once in 10 minutes in thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I have created a rest API call in Thingsboard PE rule chain, just to check and confirm that the integration and data convertor is working properly simply it was an watchdog, so i created like whenever I receive a telemetry data this rest API call will happen, more likely it will be around 100 calls per minute, so I wish to create a timer using some script or something which will have a timer in it and will check when a new telemetry data comes in and if it is greater than 10 minutes it will make the rest API call and reset the timer else will ignore the message, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the timestamp of the previous telemetry for this asset (you may have to alter your incoming rulechain and store this as an asset variable ('last_received') if it doesn't have a timestamp in the telemetry).

Add the asset variable to the message metadata.

In your api rulechain, add a node to check if the current time is more than 10 minutes greater than the asset 'last_received' timestamp. If true -> call the api, else nothing.

```
return Date.now() > +metadata.last_received;
```